# Style bootstrap dropdown button input text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a small issue with Twitter Bootstrap's [dropdown](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns) buttons. I noticed that although it is possible to style the size of the buttons via `.btn-large`, `.btn-small` etc, the text style inside the dropdown does not change. For that matter, there doesn't seem to be any preset classes for text sizes other than headings and the `small` tag.

Is there any way I can change the style of the dropdown list to fit the button via the bootstrap classes (so small buttons get small text, mini buttons get mini text etc)? This must surely be an easy question yet I haven't been able to find a solution so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font-size for the dropdown `ul` elements is set using the selector

```
.btn-group > .btn, .btn-group > .dropdown-menu, .btn-group > .popover { ... }
```

so it is not dependent on the button size; and the `ul` themselves are not given a class that corresponds to the button size class.

But you can select the list that *follows* a button with a specific class and set your own font-size, like this:

```
.btn-group > .btn-small ~ .dropdown-menu {
  font-size:10px;
}
```

Comment: Oops, don’t know how that even got in there … updated my answer, thanks for the feedback!